# Using multithreading in rxjava2 but it didn't pass to onSuccess or onError

Tags: java, android, multithreading, rx-java2

I am new to RxJava in android and trying to call method to query the SQLite. When using the same thread it successfull to pass the query result to the view. But, when i try to using different trhead by using `subscribeOn()` it doesn't work. How to fix this?

```
public void fetchNaskah() {
compositeDisposable.add(naskahRepository.getNaskah()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(mainScheduler)
    .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<NaskahDao>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<NaskahDao> naskahDaos) {
            if (naskahDaos.isEmpty()) {
                mainView.setFetchNaskahListError(true);
            } else {
                // Collections.sort(naskahDaos1);
                mainView.updateNaskahList(naskahDaos);
                mainView.setFetchNaskahListError(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            mainView.setFetchNaskahListError(true);
        }
    }));
```

}

rxJavaVersion = `2.1.16`

rxAndroidVersion = `2.0.2`

```
@Override
```

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

```
rvListNaskah.setHasFixedSize(true);
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

databaseNaskah = new NaskahDbImpl(getApplication());
mainPresenter = new MainPresenter(this, databaseNaskah,
        AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

listNaskah = new ArrayList<>();

mainPresenter.fetchNaskah();

if(!listNaskah.isEmpty()) {
    rvNaskahAdapter = new MainNaskahAdapter(this, listNaskah);
    rvListNaskah.setAdapter(rvNaskahAdapter);
    rvListNaskah.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
}
```

}

I try to debug it again and found that it called the onSuccess, but it didn't update the RecyclerView
[Debugger screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KApUr.png)

this is the Activity method

```
@Override
public void updateNaskahList(List<NaskahDao> naskahDaos) {
    listNaskah = naskahDaos;
    Log.d("naskahDaos", naskahDaos.toString());
    rvNaskahAdapter = new MainNaskahAdapter(this, listNaskah);
    rvNaskahAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    rvListNaskah.setAdapter(rvNaskahAdapter);
}
```

## Solved

This is because of fetchNaskah call getNaskah in a different thread from UI Thread it should be set the recyclearview first.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    rvListNaskah.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);


    databaseNaskah = new NaskahDbImpl(getApplication());
    mainPresenter = new MainPresenter(this, databaseNaskah,
            AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    listNaskah = new ArrayList<>();

    mainPresenter.fetchNaskah();

//        if(!listNaskah.isEmpty()) {
//            rvNaskahAdapter = new MainNaskahAdapter(this, listNaskah);
//            rvListNaskah.setAdapter(rvNaskahAdapter);
//            rvListNaskah.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
//        }
    rvListNaskah.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

}
```

The `if line` i commented above will work if the fetchNaskah call getNaskah in  syncronous. So i just commented it and set the layout manager without checking the list if it's empty because the list will come later.

Comment: Sorry for late response, this is the Activity that call `fetchNaskah()`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `compositeDisposable` was already disposed, and thus disposes the new observable when it is added.

Then without the `subscribeOn` it would work because it synchronously finishes the observable, meaning it finishes before `CompositeDisposable.add` is ever called. This means it is able to finish before it gets disposed.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Yes when i try to debug it using debugger it shows `disposed true`. I don't know how to do this properly. Can you give some resource i can read, i have try to articles about this but can't understand how to use rxjava2 in proper. I follow this ytb video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwBGnN06Kso)